# Creating a Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription fails

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azureportal

I have been instructed by the AzureSupport twitter account to create a post here about an Azure Service Bus issue I'm running into. (Original Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/heyimjacooob/status/940769610588086272)

Basically all attempts to create a subscription for a Service Bus Topic fail. I have tried in Chrome, Safari and Firefox - all behave the same way. The creation bade validates successfully, and allows me to click the "Create" button - but after I am taken back to the previous blade it gives me the following message;

[image: Azure Portal Screenshot]

Comment: Just a hunch...Can you try with `1.00:00:00`?

Comment: The message TTL and lock duration fields have a dropdown attached for the time unit (days, hours, minutes, seconds). So putting `1.00:00:00` in to the field causes the validation to fail ("The value can contain only numbers, and it cannot be less than 1").

Answer (score 1):

I was informed that this was a regression in the portal due to a recent deployment and it has since been fixed. A fix for all the regions would be rolled out as well. Sorry for the inconvenience.